# Simple shell script works in cygwin but not on solaris

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, cygwin, solaris

I'm trying to store the output of a bash command in a variable. I'm pretty new to shell scripting, but so far, I have the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
MOSTRECENTMOD="$(echo | ls -t | head -n1)"
echo "$MOSTRECENTMOD"
```

This works just fine in cygwin, but not on Solaris. Any ideas? I am using Unix newlines. I tried a lot of things, but it just doesn't seem to work.

On Solaris, it just outputs:

```
$(echo | ls -t | head -n1)
```

when run.

Thank you.

Comment: umh, there are people still using Solaris?! :-)

Comment: @Franci: yes, there are people still using Solaris.  There are also people using other non-Linux variants of Unix which are more nearly in a state of rigor mortis than Solaris.

Answer (score 4):

The standard `/bin/sh` on Solaris is fairly strictly a System V Bourne Shell.  It is categorically not a POSIX-compatible shell, and does not understand the `$(...)` notation (amongst quite a number of other differences, of greater or lesser importance).  That means to continue use `/bin/sh`, you will need to change the `$(..)` notation to use backticks (which are a pain to show in inline Markdown - I've tried all sorts of sequences without success:

```
`...`
```

Alternatively, if your machine has `/bin/bash`, specify that on the shebang line; otherwise, specify `/bin/ksh` which does support `$(...)` notation and many other useful features.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `$( ... )` syntax is from Bash, not standard sh.  Use backquotes (`` `echo | ls -t | head -n1` ``) or change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` (assuming that exists on your system).

Comment: because what you're saying (about `$()` being bash-specific) is incorrect. Compare with Jonathan's answer, which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have too many quotes. Get rid of the quotes on the first line, and it should work.

Comment: I believe it is a shell issue (lack of `$( ... )` in `/bin/sh`), not a quoting issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solaris 10 and older /bin/sh isn't POSIX compatible for legacy/upward compatibility reasons. If you want to keep your script unchanged, which I would recommend, you need to switch to a shell that support the posix $() notation, like /bin/ksh, /usr/xpg4/bin/sh or bash.

eg:

```
#!/bin/xpg4/bin/sh
MOSTRECENTMOD="$(echo | ls -t | head -n1)"
echo "$MOSTRECENTMOD"
```

Note also that Solaris 11 (Express) has a compatible /bin/sh so this won't be required.